# Channel Forms - Get selected relationship entry

Tags: relationships

When using channel forms, `{exp:channel:form}`, how do I get the selected entry of a specific relationship field?

I dont want to use custom fields because it can't be used more than once.

I also cannot use the code that shows related entries for this in `{exp:channel:form}`. I don't know why.

```
{field}
   {field:name}
{/field}
```

So, is there any simple way to do this? I will be very surprised if this is not a feature.

Comment: If you're trying to allow editing of the relationship field within your form, have you tried using the field tag with your relationship field name: {field:my_relationship_field_name}?

Comment: Can you post your current template code as a starting point?

Comment: @Romans-8---31-39 The problem with that approach is that I have no control of the markup. That is why I don't use that solution.